# Symfony 3.3 - How can the container know the tag of the service when autowiring is enabled?

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.3

I have a service which has two tags, `extended_type` and `name`.

With autowiring enabled, how can I define these tags?

> Edit:
>   This is my class form extension

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateTimeType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
class DateTimeTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    public function getExtendedType()
    {
        return DateTimeType::class;
    }

    public function buildView( FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options )
    {
        $view->vars['date_time_help'] = 'Format d-m-Y.';
    }

}
```

Form type extension service need to define two tags `extended_type` and `name`

Comment: I think it would be easier to answer this question with more information about what you are trying to do, and some example code.

Comment: I need to create a form Extension. So my service has 2 tags **name** and **extended_type**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting in Symfony 3.3, if you enable autoconfigure, then some tags are automatically applied for you like `twig.extension`.
enable autoconfigure does not work for all tags. Many tags have required attributes, like event listeners, where you also need to specify the event name and method in your tag. Autoconfigure works only for tags without any required tag attributes

In your case, you need to  override your sevice in the `app/config/service.yml` and explicitly define your tags like this:

```
AppBundle\Service\YourService:
        tags:
            - { name: service1, extended_type: service2 }
```

Comment: Thanks. So without overriding my service, The extension type form doesn't work.

Comment: Indeed, there is an [open PR to pull this information from the extension class instead](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/24530). But that won't be a thing before Symfony 4.1.